# Glassfish 3.1 remote standalone (application) client

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

Hi I am trying to run a remote standalone application client on Glassfish 3.1 server.

The problem is very strange and I have spent a lot of time trying to find this:

I have set the following `iiop` properties:

```
public static InitialContext setProps4Connect() {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","com.sun.enterprise.naming");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state","com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");

    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.0.81");
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

     try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
        return ic;
      } catch (Exception re) {
        DialogFinancial("soel.utils.setProps4Connect() InitialContext. Σφάλμα κατά τον ορισμό των παραμέτρων!", re.toString(), 2, -1);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I used the following code to update one record of the parameter `"SOM"`:

```
    String ID = "SOM";
    try {
        Parameters parameters = parametersFacade.find(ID);
        if(parameters==null){
                throw new Exception("searched protocol not found");
        }

        parameters.setDescriptionel(jTextFieldDescription_EL.getText());
        parameters.setDescriptionen(jTextFieldDescription_EN.getText());
        //****************************************************************//
    //update.setType(jComboBoxType.getSelectedItem().toString());
        parameters.setFuse(jTextFieldFUse.getText());
    parameters.setComments(jTextAreaComments.getText());
        parametersFacade.edit(parameters);
```

When I execute my remote client, in the `server.log` file I get an error that says:

> Query: InsertObjectQuery(iesoel.remote.entity.Parametersdetails[ parametersdetailsPK=null ])

And now starts the strange things. I try to get a field from `parameters`:

System.out.println(parameters.setDescriptionel());

This works fine. Now if I change the property from:

```
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.0.81");
```

to

```
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "www1");
```

Then everything is working fine.

Please note this problem is only on GlassFish 3.1 not on GlassFish 3.0.1. So if I understand, this is not a network problem. Any ideas?

Comment: The parts of the code that I can see look fine.  Maybe you could add some of the session bean you're calling to help give more information to work with.

Comment: Also, are you using this glassfish on the same machine that you're running the remote client on?  Is there a firewall or VPN involved?  I've seen some strange things happen when glassfish's ORB isn't configured correctly and the client is on a VPN.  As a guess, try setting your orb listener's Network Address to the DNS for the machine.  (Configurations/server-config/ORB/IIOP Listeners/orb-listener-1).  The default for this is 0.0.0.0 and I saw that clients on 10.0.x.x networks could do Corba/RMI, but clients on 192.168.x.x networks could not get through.

Comment: Jim I have the same proplem to an other network with 10.0.x.x networks.

Comment: Following the code off the session beans ParametersFacade
@Stateless(mappedName="iesoel.Parameters")
public class ParametersFacade extends AbstractFacade<Parameters> implements ParametersFacadeLocal, ParametersFacadeRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "IESOEL-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ParametersFacade() {
        super(Parameters.class);
    }
    
}

Comment: If I try to use the glassfish 3.1 on the same machine:
with 
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.0.41");
the same problem.
with 
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
no problem
with 
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "127.0.0.1");
no problem
Please note the GF 3.1 is on Centos Linux 5.6 but I try to use and GF 3.1 on windows XP but the same problem.

The Configurations/server-config/ORB/IIOP Listeners/orb-listener-1 is the default 0.0.0.0 but I try with the IP of the machine 192.168.0.17 but the same problem.

Comment: Somewhere I read that comment from the /etc/hosts file the
#127.0.0.1 but the same problem

Comment: At the last the code the call the ejb

InitialContext ic = iesoel.utils.utilities.setProps4Connect();
            
parametersFacade = (ParametersFacadeRemote)  ic.lookup("iesoel.Parameters");

Comment: Also here is firewall. But I remind you that there is no problem with GF 3.0.1

Comment: For my glassfish to work property on Redhat [RHEL 5] (which is essentially the same as CentOS, right?) the /etc/hosts needs to have the hostname matched with the ip address.  So if /etc/sysconfig/network says your hostname is gfdev, then your /etc/hosts needs the entry: 192.168.0.17    gfdev localhost   Sorry I can't tell you easily if this really affects corba/rmi, but I will say that this is how mine (gf 3.0.1) is configured and working.  If it is working on 3.0.1, I would say make the /etc/hosts match that machine.  If they're on the same machine, then I don't know.

Comment: Jim yes my GF 3.0.1 is working fine but not the GF 3.1 this is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for solutions, I found the following link with a solution: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/N2KaoS4G06nDbgqxPmzu

I added the following to the `persistence.xml` file:

```
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="false"/>
</properties>
```

I deleted the `<properties/>` entry, and it now is working fine.

Please note, the problem is only with Glassfish 3.1 and not with GlassFish 3.0.1. I think it's a bug.